# HTML2PDF - fopen() failed to open stream: Permission denied in/html2pdf/_tcpdf_5.0.002/tcpdf.php on line 6168

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework2, ubuntu-12.04, html2pdf

I got a problem with the HTML2PDF library (i use PHP with Zend Framework 2).

I'm on a linux ubuntu dedicated server and the destination folder for my .pdf file got chmod 777. I even tried chmod 666 ... but i still get the same error :

> [warn] [client *.*.*.*] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  fopen(/my_absolute_path/file.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /my_absolute_path/html2pdf/_tcpdf_5.0.002/tcpdf.php on line 6168

Any answers ?
Thx much

**EDIT**

@Novocaine88, you're right :-)

Here is my very simple code :

```
// Set the file path
$path = ROOT_PATH.'/data/myFolder_chmod_777/file.pdf';

// Create the pdf document
require_once ROOT_PATH . '/vendor/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php';
$pdf = new \HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');

// Get the content
$content = $this->getHtmlContent($required_param);

// Forge PDF doc
$pdf->WriteHTML($content);

// Save doc
$pdf->Output($path, 'F');
```

This is (approximately) the code i get from the official site of HTML2PDF (http://html2pdf.fr/example).
When i use it on my local machine, everything works fine, but on the distant server ...

**SOLUTION**

After reading my code a hundred times, i found the problem.
This is stupid, i didn't set the path correctly.

Here is the code :

```
// Set the file path
$path = ROOT_PATH.'/data/folder/myFolder_chmod_777/file.pdf';
```

It works now !

Comment: why not show some code, that might help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

BTW you can ommit the ROOT_PATH constant.

Look into your ZF2's public/index.php file.

```
/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));
```

So your code should also work with

```
// Set the file path
$path = '/data/folder/myFolder_chmod_777/file.pdf';
```